# Retrieve data from request.end() in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, httprequest, unirest

I want to use result of unirest request to another file in **Node.js** but I can not get data from **request.end()** function to outer variable.

Code is below:

```
request.end(function (response) {
        if(response.error) {
            console.log("AUTHENTICATION ERROR: ", response.error);
        } else {
            callback(null, response.body);
        }

        console.log("AUTHENTICATION BODY: ", response.body);
    });

var result = authentication(function(error, response) {
    var authenticationToken = response.access_token;

    if(authenticationToken != null) {
        console.log("Token: ", authenticationToken);

        return authenticationToken;
    }
});
```

I want to get **authenticationToken** value to export with `module.exports` for another modules.

I am using **unirest http library**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a callback function, and is treated as parameter, not a function that returns value.

You can do this though:

```
var result;
authentication(function(error, response) {
    var authenticationToken = response.access_token;

    if(authenticationToken != null) {
        console.log("Token: ", authenticationToken);

        module.exports.result = authenticationToken; // setting value of result, instead of passing it back
    }
});
```

you can use `result` variable now.
But be careful, its an asynchronous function, so you may not be able to use it immediately, until a value is assigned to it, within a callback function.

### To export result value:

```
module.exports.result = null;
```

#### Example

*m1.js*

```
setTimeout(() => {
   module.exports.result = 0;
}, 0);

module.exports.result = null;
```

*app.js*

```
const m1 = require('./m1.js');

console.log(JSON.stringify(m1));

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(m1));

}, 10);
```

*Output*

```
{"result":null}
{"result":0}
```

so you can keep using variable `result`, once the variable is assigned it would contain the value.

Comment: I am getting same result. **result** variable still null.

Comment: Function must treat like running synchronous. How can I do that? The problem is asynchronous function.

Comment: your result is null, because function hasn't run until the API has run..